# Live Agent ports/ip addresses

Tags: liveagent

What ports and IP addresses does Live Agent need for an agent to be able to connect to the chat from inside a corporate network?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the endpoint for Live Agent of your org on the following page:

```
Setup > Customize > Live Agent > Settings
```

And as this https endpoint it uses 443 port